# Subscriptions with Paypal IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I am adding subscriptions to a site using Paypal IPN which works very well, I can successfully create a new subscription and verify it. The subscription has a two week free trial. The guide was unfortunately a little vague on subscription statuses.

At the moment, the users account gets subscribed status once subscr_signup or subscr_payment is received and gets removed when either subscr_cancel or subscr_failed is received. I believe this is correct but it's best to make sure.

Also what is subscr_eot? the IPN guide describes it as "subscription’s end-of-term." Does this get triggered after the trial period is over?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`subscr_eot` is sent when a user's last paid interval has expired.  `subscr_cancel` is sent as soon as the use cancels the subscription - for example:

User signs up on day 1 for a subscription which is billed once a month.
`subscr_signup` is sent immediately, `subscr_payment` is sent as soon as payment goes through (usually immediately as well).

On day 13, the user cancels.  `subscr_cancel` is immediately sent, although the user has technically paid through to day 30.  Cancelling at this point is up to you.

On day 30, `subscr_eot` is sent - the user has cancelled, and this is the day which his last payment paid until.

Not much changes with trial subscriptions - if a user cancels before a trial subscription is up, `subscr_cancel` is sent immediately, and `subscr_eot` is sent at the end of the trial.

Comment: I'm not sure this is necessarily true. I think it depends on the type of subscription they have, starting with I/S etc

Comment: I hear that subscr_* is the old way. Is that true? Anyway, I'm trying to get these txn_type values figured out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855287/parsing-paypal-subscription-ran-out

Comment: Just to add to this - afaik - if you weren't doing a free trial, then 'subscr_signup' is sent only if the first payment was successful as well. So you could listen to only subscr_signup and subscr_eot to activate / deactivate subscriptions.

Comment: @Peter after subscr_eot ends, do we ask user to sign up for subscription again or modify existing subscription? so would it be subscr_modify or subscr_signup on after the end of the term. or for canclled users?

Comment: Thank you very much for describing subscr_eot

Comment: @Webcognoscere You should only activate the subscription when you get the money, unless it's a free trial.

Comment: this is a very helpful answer, I wish the PayPal docs had stuff worded like this

Comment: answer below from ajbeaven is worth a look. I can confirm today I worked with some 'classic web software': subscr_eot happens before subscr_cancel. In our case we ignore subscr_eot and focus on subscr_cancel to terminate an account. In the DB I can see paypal changed this as members prior to 2010 have subscr_eot but members who left as recently as last month have subscr_cancel. In short: we have paying members who get subscr_eot for short times and later it changes to suscr_payment. https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/PayPal-Reporting/PayPal-IPN-subscr-eot-sent-after-subscr-cancel/td-p/1453213

Comment: This belongs here:
https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/ipn/IPNandPDTVariables/

Answer (score 38):

Also, one interesting detail is how `subscr_eot` works with `subscr_failed`.

It looks like `subscr_eot` comes after the **FINAL** `subscr_failed`.  So if in your account you set it to automatically retry failed payments 3 times, then it should go like this:

first failed payment => subscr_failed
second failed payment => subscr_failed
third failed payment => subscr_failed and subscr_eot

so basically in your code you can set `subscr_failed` to trigger an email like

> hi user, 
>   please take moment to check
>   your payment info, you may need to
>   update the credit card expiration
>   date, etc.  You still have access,
>   we'll try again in a few days.

And setup `subscr_eot` to actually turn their subscription off and trigger an email like

> Sorry, we still havent' gotten payment
>   and have taken your profile down.  You
>   can still reactivate it by logging in and updating your payment info

Basically this is the "nice" way of doing it so customers have a grace period, and their account isn't shut off unexpectedly just because of an expired credit card or something like that.

Comment: Do failed payments and the sending of subscr_eot notifications still work as they did in 2009?

Comment: @ajbeaven: It would appear that since the post was updated in April, the information is still current.

Comment: @BrainArmstrong after subscr_eot ends, do we ask user to sign up for subscription again or modify existing subscription? so would it be subscr_modify or subscr_signup on after the end of the term. or for canclled users?

Comment: subscr_eot is not the final. (in the past this may have been true) but as recently as today I can confirm subscr_eot happens before subscr_cancel. to confirm: subscr_cancel is the end all beat all. subscr_eot seems to happen when a Subscription expired, HOWEVER, a user can renew and subscr_payment can be sent shortly after that. Reference the official docs as of 2023: https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/ipn/IPNandPDTVariables/

Answer (score 10):

The thread posted by Chris has been updated recently.

Sometime in 2010, PayPal stopped using subscr_eot when a user cancelled their account. After a number of complaints, they reinstated this, but took 6 months to do so. All this means is that you can once again handle your subscription notifications as described by Peter in the accepted answer.

**From a PayPal representative:**

> subscr_cancel means the profile is
>   canceled and there will not be future
>   payments. However, if the buyer has
>   already paid for the current billing
>   cycle as they are charged up-front,
>   then you can use the subscr_eot to
>   terminate the profile.

Still unsure what happens in the event of multiple failed payment attempts, however. PayPal documentation at the moment is terrible.

Comment: Sure is. There's very little authoritative documentation about API/IPN-related stuff, and what there is is usually contradicted by *other* documentation, or that bastard called reality.

Comment: yeah, like that day that the _payment ipn happened before the _signup ipn :D

Comment: You are correct. Your answer is now the right one in this case. The previously selected answer was right 14 years ago, but I can confirm that today I worked with some lets say 'classic web software' and subscr_eot happens BEFORE the subscr_cancel.