# When does Paypal send subscr_eot?

Tags: paypal-subscriptions

can we rely solely on subscr_eot to activate/deactivate an account?

Assume  we have the following scenario:

1. On 9/16, a customer pays using Paypal for a monthly recurring
   service.
2. With 24 hours, Paypal sends "subscr_signup" and
   followed by "subscr_payment". At this time, the application will
   grant the user access.
3. ??

The question, will Paypal send an EOT before attempting to collect the payment on 10/16 or would it send it before?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subscriptions with Paypal IPN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061683/subscriptions-with-paypal-ipn)

Answer (score 14):

`subscr_eot` means that the subscription has expired, either because the subscriber cancelled it or it has a fixed term (implying a fixed number of payments) and it has now expired with no further payments being due. It is sent at the end of the term, instead of any payment that would otherwise have been due on that date.

Comment: Thanks..

I am still not sure if that means they would send the subscr_eot on 10/17 or on the same day they tried to collect the payment and they weren't successful on that. I am trying to see If I must create  create a field in the database that stands for expiration date or I can rely solely on the order of transactions that are sent by Paypal.

Comment: They won't try to collect the payment at all. No payment is due. The subscription has expired. The last payment was collected one whole period ago. I would certainly advise you to maintain your own expiration date. You don't get this message just because a payment failed.

Comment: In my test I receive subscr_eot for every subscription that doesn't have recurring activated. So I receive it along with subscr_signup and subscr_payment. Not logical.

Comment: You don't want to know that the term has ended?

Comment: For me this answer it's exactly what happen http://stackoverflow.com/a/1195246/2528167

Comment: @AlbertoFernández That agrees with what I wrote here.

Comment: Yes @EJP, I have upvoted you, that is only a more complete answer. Thank you

Comment: Hello I know it's pretty late, but does anybody  know the return value of txn_type if it's reccuring payment?