# paypal next payment date calculation

Tags: php, paypal

I have a paypal recurring payments for my client. However, according to the IPN and auto return result, I cannot see the next payment date. On the other hand, I have followed the following rules to calculate myself. The result in sandbox is wrong. For example, I submitted a transaction on 31 Mar and the paypal sandbox showed the next payment due is "30 Apr". I do not expect this result according to paypal's rules. How can I get the next payment date?

I have attached the rules below.

---

The rules from paypal:
How Subscriptions with Monthly Billing Cycles Work

For monthly billing cycles, recurring payments are collected on the same day of the month. If the initial recurring payment falls on the 31st, PayPal eventually adjusts the billing cycle to the 1st of the month. If the initial recurring payment falls on the 29th or 30th, PayPal adjusts the billing cycle to the 1st of the month on the following February.
When Monthly Recurring Payments Are Due and Collected on the 31st

The subscription terms are:

```
$25.99 USD a month; the subscriber signs up on Thursday, July 31.
```

The subscriber is billed as follows:

```
Thursday, July 31 = $25.99 USD
Saturday, August 31 = $25.99 USD
Wednesday, October 1= $25.99 USD
Saturday, November 1= $25.99 USD
and so on...
```

Notice that no recurring monthly payment was collected in September, but recurring payments were collected roughly every 30 days.
When Monthly Recurring Payments Are Due and Collected on the 30th

The subscription terms are:

```
$25.99 USD a month; the subscriber signs up on Tuesday, December 30.
```

The subscriber is billed as follows:

```
Tuesday, December 30 = $25.99 USD
Friday, January 30 = $25.99 USD
Sunday, March 1= $25.99 USD
Wednesday, April 1= $25.99USD
and so on...
```

Notice that no recurring monthly payment was collected in February, but recurring payments were collected roughly every 30 days.
**

Comment: Yup this seems to be a bit of a PITA.  Did you ever get to the bottom of this with a decent solution?  I'm not sure whether I should just use the following [and just charge every 30 days instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26595624/894792)